# Which container implementation docker is using

Tags: lxc, docker

Docker is based on Linux containers and control groups. But I would like to know which implementation of Linux containers , docker is using? Is it using the native/default (LXC execution environment ) of Linux or they have their own implementation of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker uses their own libcontainer library after they switched from using LXC in 2014.

LXC uses their (www.linuxcontainers.org)  liblxc library.

Both libraries utilize the linux kernel namespaces technology.
LWN had a multi-part blog on namespaces:  https://lwn.net/Articles/531114/

Comment: Thanks , that clear to me now , it means the libcontainer is the default in docker. What if i want docker to use LXC ?

Answer (score 4):

With both Docker and LXC, the core implementation of the container technology is the same: it's provided by Linux kernel itself. The kernel provides multiple mechanisms such as namespaces (mount, network, pid, ...), cgroups and others. So both docker and lxc uses these features to simplify container management and to automate particular use cases.

This means that both docker and lxc wouldn't exists without features provided by linux kernel. The main difference between lxc and docker is which set of linux kernel features/api is used and what workflows and usesaces are supported.

Comment: you mean that docker dont use lxc ?